# Why does SOAPUI return bad request?

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui

I have created a `soapui` project to test [this wsdl](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl)

When sending this request

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:x/="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
    <x/:CelsiusToFahrenheit>
       <!--Optional:-->
       <x/:Celsius>30</x/:Celsius>
    </x/:CelsiusToFahrenheit>
 </soapenv:Body>
```

I get bad request in raw response

```
  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
  Cache-Control: private,public
  Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
  Date: Sun, 28 Feb 2016 17:33:28 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is so trivial due to the special character in the namespace (`x/`), which can be found by Validating the request( clicking keys 'Alt+v` in the request editor)

Could not figure it out that why such special character is coming when soapUI generates the request

**What should be done in order to make the request valid?**

Please change the request to below(replaced `x/` to `x`):

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <x:CelsiusToFahrenheit>
         <x:Celsius>30</x:Celsius>
      </x:CelsiusToFahrenheit>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Below is the screen shot of successful response upon changing the request as above.

[image: CelsiusToFahrenheit request and response]